# DRF validation - returns error 500 when error in Model.clean

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the fields `refundable` and `refundable_price` in my model. I need to be sure that there is `refundable_price` not `None` in case `refundable` is `True`.

Since I want it everywhere, I've overridden `SubOffer.clean` method:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def save(self, **kwargs):
    self.full_clean()
    super().save(**kwargs)

def clean(self):
    super().clean()
    if self.refundable and self.refundable_price is None:
        raise ValidationError("V prípade refundovateľnej ponuky je nutné zadať sumu (je možné zadať aj 0)")
```

And I use `ModelViewSet`.

```
class SubOfferViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = SubOfferSerializer
    filterset_fields = {
        # 'approved_by': ['exact'],
        # 'approved_dt': ['gte', 'lte', 'gt', 'lt'],
    }

    def get_queryset(self):
        return SubOffer.objects.all()
```

The weird thing is that when I send `POST` to the `ViewSet` it returns `500` instead of `JSON` errors if there is an error in `Suboffer.clean`. Other errors work correctly.

It's the same when I use `AJAX` and when I use `DRF API Viewer`.

[image]

[image]
How is that possible and how to make it work properly?

Comment: Please show all the relevant code. Also please show us the actual 500 error.

Comment: @Kareem I've added more information but I think the problem is in the Model.

Answer (score 12):

A clean way that will handle all of your Validation errors (and any other errors you might want) is to have a custom `EXCEPTION_HANDLER` that converts the Django
`ValidationError` to a DRF one.

See:

```py
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError as DjangoValidationError
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError as DRFValidationError
from rest_framework.serializers import as_serializer_error
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler as drf_exception_handler


def exception_handler(exc, context):

    if isinstance(exc, DjangoValidationError):
        exc = DRFValidationError(as_serializer_error(exc))

    return drf_exception_handler(exc, context)


"""
In settings:

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'path.to_module.drf.exception_handler',
}
"""
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/twidi/9d55486c36b6a51bdcb05ce3a763e79f

A more in-depth example: https://github.com/HackSoftware/Django-Styleguide-Example/blob/9761c7592af553084e95bb5f8f9407a173aac66f/styleguide_example/api/exception_handlers.py

Comment: Life saver! Especially the as_serializer_error. Keeps your API responding the way you expect it.

Comment: I love you man, You are a life saver

Answer (score 5):

By defaul DRF handle only `APIException` (see [source](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/95d4843abeecea96754a147f4f2cca33e620ad09/rest_framework/views.py#L86)). Since you are rising `Django's`ValidationError`instead of DRF's`Validation` error, this handler returns None.

So to fix this, you can use `ValidationError` from DRF:

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError
```

or which is better to write your own [custom exception_handler](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling)::

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    # Call REST framework's default exception handler first,
    # to get the standard error response.
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)
    if response is None and isinstance(exc, ValidationError):
        return Response(status=400)

    return response
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Replacing the django.core.exceptions version of ValidationError with the rest_framework.exceptions version in my model did the trick!